# Access property values with an attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, custom-attributes

How do I access the value of a property inside an attribute class. I'm writing a custom validation attribute that needs to check the value of the property against a regular expression. The 
For Instance:

```
public class MyAttribute
{
public MyAttribute (){}

//now this is where i want to use the value of the property using the attribute. The attribute can be use in different classed
public string DoSomething()
{
//do something with the property value
}
}

Public class MyClass
{
[MyAttribute]
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use a regular expression validation attribute, then you can inherit from `RegularExpressionAttribute`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8431253/486434 for an example of how to do that.

However, if you want to do something more complex and access the value you can inherit from `ValidationAttribute` and override the 2 virtual methods `IsValid`. E.g.:

```
public class MyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // Do your own custom validation logic here
        return base.IsValid(value);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```