# ASP MVC 4 Using a class to validate a get/set within a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

working on a project right now and I'm relatively new to MVC, I have a model which looks something like

```
public class MyViewModel
{
public string check1 {get;set;}
public string check2 {get;set;}
}
```

I also have a class which I want to use to validate these checks using a custom regex, such as

```
public class WebCommon
{
    public static bool Validation(string validate)
    {
        bool validatestatus = false;
        Regex check = new Regex(my regex here);
        if (check.IsMatch(validate))
        {
            validatestatus = true;
            return validatestatus;
        }
        else
        {
            return validationstatus;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what I'd like to do is call that method inside the webcommon class, inside the model itself to check when I take in the values for the get;sets in my model, and if it returns false, then I want it to throw an error within the view saying that it is not a valid input. Thanks!

Comment: A custom validator would be a better solution.  Then you could just decorate the properties with the validator.

Comment: Hi @Maess, I've actually already used a custom validator but the requirements for this project insist that I use a custom method within a class so I dont have to remember this custom 'validator' for everytime I need to call it.

Comment: This question [here][1] is about custom regular expression with ASP.Net MVC


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431007/how-can-i-set-a-regularexpression-data-annotations-regular-expression-argument

Comment: Interesting, requirements that require you to violate separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431007/how-can-i-set-a-regularexpression-data-annotations-regular-expression-argument) is about making custom regular expression attrbutes and should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out either [Regular Expression Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx)

Or [implement and IValidatableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic4.aspx)