# Data Annotations - using an attribute extension and storing regular expressions in a resource file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, custom-attributes

I am currently working with ***MVC4*** data annotations to handle validation.  I am working on a site that will be very much international and as such I keep all of my text in resource files.

I also want to keep regular expressions for validation in resource files so I can use the same code to check, for example, ***Post Codes (UK)*** and ***Zip Codes (US)*** just by using a different RegEx (and resources for the different names etc).

I have the below attribute which is already pulling the error message from a resource file.  How can I have it get the regex from a resource file too?

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\w]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[\w]?\s?[0-9]{1,2}[\w]{1,2}$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "validPostcode")]
```

**EDIT (AGAIN)**

**Where I am now**

Following the answer below and some additional searching around, I have the following:

In `Global.asax.cs` I have added the below line to ensure client side validation is invoked

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(LocalisedAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

In my model, I have this call to the attribute extension

```
[Localised(typeof(Resources.FormValidation), "postcodeRegEx", "postcodeMsg")]
```

And finally, the attribute extension for localised regex validation

```
public class LocalisedAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public LocalisedAttribute(Type resource, string regularExpression, string errorMessage) 
        : base(GetRegex(regularExpression))
    {
        ErrorMessageResourceType = resource;
        ErrorMessageResourceName = errorMessage;
    }

    private static string GetRegex(string value) 
    {
        return Resources.FormValidation.ResourceManager.GetString(value);


    }
}
```

This works, but ONLY the first time I use it when starting the application.

I am going to open another question to get around that problem - it's not directly related to the original request, doesn't seem to be relevant to most peoples implementation and doesn't seem to be specific to data annotations.

Comment: Do you use different CultureInfos?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: I think if you want to get localized resources you have to decide where to get culture info name and change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already have some extended kind of `RegularExpressionAttribute` implementation, that allows to use resources for regex pattern. It looks like:

```
public class RegularExpressionExAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute, IClientValidatable
{        
    private Regex regex { get; set; }
    private string pattern;

    private string resourceName;
    private Type resourceType;

    /// <summary>
    /// constructor, calls base with ".*" basic regex
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resName">resource key</param>
    /// <param name="resType">resource type</param>
    public RegularExpressionExAttribute(string resName, Type resType)
        : base(".*")
    {
        resourceName = resName;
        resourceType = resType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// override RegularExpressionAttribute property
    /// </summary>
    public new string Pattern
    {
        get
        {
            SetupRegex();
            return pattern;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// loads regex from resources
    /// </summary>
    private void SetupRegex()
    {
        ResourceAccessor ra = new ResourceAccessor(resourceName, resourceType);
        pattern = ra.resourceValue;
        regex = new Regex(pattern);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// override validation with our regex
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">string for validation</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        SetupRegex();
        string val = Convert.ToString(value);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
            return true;
        var m = regex.Match(val);
        return (m.Success && (m.Index == 0));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metaData, ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRegexRule(base.ErrorMessageString, this.Pattern);
    }
}
```

Also it's using `ResourceAccessor` class to get regex out of resources

```
public class ResourceAccessor
{
    private string resourceName;
    private Type resourceType;
    private Func<string> accessor;
    private string _resourceValue;

    public ResourceAccessor(string resourceName, Type resourceType)
    {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.resourceType = resourceType;
    }

    public string resourceValue
    {
        get
        {
            SetupAccessor();
            return accessor();
        }
    }

    private void SetupAccessor()
    {
        if (accessor != null) //already set
            return;
        string localValue = _resourceValue;
        bool flag1 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName);
        bool flag2 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(localValue);
        bool flag3 = resourceType != (Type)null;
        if (flag1 == flag2)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't set resource value");
        }
        if (flag3 != flag1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Resource name and type required");
        }
        if (flag1)
            PropertyLookup();
        else
        {
            accessor = (Func<string>)(() => localValue);
        }
    }

    private void PropertyLookup()
    {
        if (resourceType == (Type)null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Resource name and type required");
        }

        PropertyInfo property = resourceType.GetProperty(resourceName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        if (property != (PropertyInfo)null)
        {
            MethodInfo getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
            if (getMethod == (MethodInfo)null || !getMethod.IsAssembly && !getMethod.IsPublic)
                property = (PropertyInfo)null;
        }
        if (property == (PropertyInfo)null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Resource type doesn't have property");
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Resource type must be string");
        }
        else
        {
            accessor = (Func<string>)(() => (string)property.GetValue((object)null, (object[])null));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is usage samples:

```
public class SignUpInput
{        
    [RegularExpressionEx("EmailValidationRegex", typeof(LocalizedResources), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "invalidEmail")]     
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This solutions works in its current form. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think yuo can extend RegularExpressionAttribute

```
public class PostCodeValidationAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        public PostCodeValidationAttribute()
            : base(Resources.PostCodeValidationExpression)
        {
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Put culture info name in session for example accordingly with user choice. And use it in

```
ResourceManager.GetString(value, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(userCulture));
```

At first you can test it with hardcode value. Something like this

```
ResourceManager.GetString(value, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
```

instead

```
ResourceManager.GetString(value, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(currentCulture));
```

or in base constructor

```
base(GetRegex(regularExpression, ""en-GB""))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I am fairly new to C# - I have created the above attribute but am unsure as to exactly how to use it.  I have replaced `[RegularExpression(@...]` with `[PostCodeValidation]` but I'm unsure how to get it to work as before.  Can you advise on what I need to put in my model?

Comment: Did you create resources with regular expressions for validation? Do you use CultureInfo for?

Comment: I have resource files with regular expressions, but at this point I have my regex and error message as strings in the extension just so I can see it working.  I'll update my question with some code...

Comment: OK, question updated.  I hope it makes sense and that there is an obvious solution I am missing!

Comment: I have updated my answer again - the issue I am now having is that it is not using the correct resource file for the regex; it only ever retrieves the expression from the defauklt resx file.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As suggested, I added the culture to base constructor and used that parameter in my `GetRegex` method.  It works perfectly, picking up the the correct expression if I set either `en-US` or `en-GB`.  A step closer!  Any thoughts on how I can get it to use the current culture?  In both the Model that uses this attribute extension and the View, everything adheres to the current culture.  It's only in this `GetRegex` where I seem to need to name the culture I want rather than have it pick up the current culture.

Comment: OK - the plot thickens.  I put a breakpoint on the return in the `GetRegex` method.  When I start the application it hits the method and I can see that it's using the hard coded culture name.  However, when I switch cultures in my app I do not hit that breakpoint which explains why it never changes.  Now I need to figure out why they method isn't used when I change cultures!

Comment: How do you switch culture in your app and where?

Comment: Question updated with some information on culture switching.  The crux of the problem is that the attributr extension isn't hit when the page is refreshed so the updated culture never makes it to the `GetRegEx` method.

Comment: I don't understand what does your last sentense mean? Can you just use in ResourceManager.GetString culture info name from Cookies, it will be there after refresh page. Now I cann't see any usages of culture info for getting correct regexp in your question.

Comment: This answer has helped me the most by far. I now have a new problem which I should move to a new question as the scope has changed completely.  Thanks for your help!