# Validation through custom validator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a `TextBox` for house number and its data type is `string` but I have to put a validation on this `TextBox` so that it only accept `integer` value.I have to use `DataAnnotations` and custom validations for this.

Comment: Use javascript regex and validate it through jquery. You can also  use foolproof http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks..But I have to use only Data Annotations and custom validations.

Comment: Yes you can use regex in your data annotation to validate the string. Check this stack link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431007/how-can-i-set-a-regularexpression-data-annotations-regular-expression-argument

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expression or Range Data Annotations

`[RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,}$", ErrorMessage = "HouseNumber error")]`

or

`[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "HouseNumber error")]
public string HouseNumber{ get; set; }`