# Replace regularexpression-string in metadataattribute

Tags: .net, razor, model-view-controller

I am writing an application that loads language texts from a database to enable internationalization, using keys in the viewmodels to find the correct text. I have modified a version of the MyLocalizationprovider from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/514321/A-Simple-and-Effective-Way-to-Localize-ASP-Net-MVC, my modified code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/TheConfuser/5f4a64ebe13254e7d45b. The code goes thru the metadata-attributes and replaces the title(DisplayName), placeholder (Prompt), errormessage (ErrorMessage) and validation errormessage (ErrorMessage). I am fetching DisplayAttribute for ErrorMessage, Prompt and Name as well as ValidationAttribute for the ErrorMessage for validation between two fields, in this case passwords. I get the keys like this:

```
if (typeName.Equals("DisplayAttribute"))
{
    nameKey = ((DisplayAttribute) attr).Name;
    placeholderKey = ((DisplayAttribute) attr).Prompt;
...
```

And then I replace the keys with values from my database. My viewmodels looks like follows:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "changepassword_newpassword_error")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Prompt = "changepassword_newpassword_placeholder", Name = "changepassword_newpassword_headline")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,12}", ErrorMessage = "changepassword_newpassword_regexerror")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

This works fine for placeholders, titles, errormessages for the field and for the validation, however I have yet any idea of how to find the RegularExpression. I thought it would exist in the ValidationAttribute as its ErrorMessage does, but I cannot find anything there. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx.

Where can I find the field for the regularexpression-string, does it even exist? 
Or should I try to write my own attribute (like [Set RegularExpression Dynamically in Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198404/set-regularexpression-dynamically-in-model)), if so can anyone help me on the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some even further searching, I found more answers that lead me to a working solution.

First, instead of listening for ValidationAttribute, which is a large attributeclass, I went down the chain and sought for RequiredAttribute and CompareAttribute, besides the DisplayAttribute. With these, I could find compareerrors, requirederrors as well as Title and Placeholder for a inputfield.

I found that there exist a RegularExpressionAttribute where I could find the field Pattern, although I could only Get the value, not Set the value. The solution was to implement a custom RegularExpressionAttribute-class that inherits from ValidationAttribute much like [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Using it vanilla as that did though not work since it did not give any validationerrors back. The solution is to inherit from IclientValidate as well. See the full code below.

```
public class CustomRegularExpressionValidateAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public string Pattern { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var password = (string)value;
        var match = Regex.Match(password, Pattern);
        if (!match.Success)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }

        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRegexRule(FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()), Pattern);
    }

}
```

My class MyLocalizationProvider reads the attributes DisplayAttribute, CompareAttribute, RequiredAttribute and CustomRegularExpressionValidateAttribute and returns the values for the specified keys in the viewmodels. A row in the viewmodel looks like this for the class:

```
[CustomRegularExpressionValidate(Pattern = "PasswordRegex", ErrorMessage = "changepassword_newpassword_regexerror")]
```

And now the full chain works. I hope this might be of help for someone.